# Website content with responsive width but fixed height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I'm building a responsive website using Bootstrap. So far, it works great if I resize the window horizontally, but if I resize the window vertically I don't want the height of the contents (Bootstrap columns, images, and other divs) to change. I haven't been able to find a good answer for this, so does anyone know what I could do to solve this problem?

Edit: I've attached a couple pictures to show what I don't want to happen.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGyQm.jpg) is what the portion of the site I'm concerned about looks like when the window has not been resized vertically.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MGOj.jpg) is what the same part looks like when the window is shrunk vertically. The text runs off the bottom of the containing div. I'd like to keep the div the same height if I shrink the window vertically, while still changing the width if the window is resized horizontally.

Sorry, I don't have a lot of experience and this is my first time posting so please let me know if I should include more info!

Edit 2: Here's my code

```css
body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #111111;
  height: auto!important;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#home-content {
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 7.5vh;
}

.col-content {
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  height: 40vh;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #555555;
}

#intro-content {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 200%;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  margin-bottom: 1vw;
  font-family: Perpetua;
  text-align: center;
}

#intro-hr {
  background-color: #444444;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -5px 0 5px 0;
}

#intro-text {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=100px, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="css/styles2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

  <div id="home-content" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="intro" class="col-lg-6">
        <div id="intro-content" class="col-content top left">
          <h2> Title </h2>

          <hr id="intro-hr">

          <p id="intro-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras placerat molestie volutpat. Nam gravida tortor id tellus pulvinar sodales. Duis sodales sagittis ex, a ultricies lacus tempus vel. Maecenas lobortis venenatis sem. Nulla at odio vehicula, volutpat
            quam eu, fermentum dolor.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="contact" class="col-lg-6">
        <div id="contact-content" class="col-content top">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use auto for col-content height and assign it a min-height instead if you want both columns to have the same size or use any other way. But the culprit here is fixed height.

Comment: Thanks so much! I added a min-height and that solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Probably height of `100vh` could help because this takes 100% of the viewport height

Comment: I've added some pictures to better show what I'm talking about, since I'm pretty sure 100vh wouldn't work. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the HTML code and related CSS Code to the post? I think I know what you might have done wrong but first I have to see the code to be sure :)

Comment: Posted the answer above with some more explanation, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the 40vh part of this css part you should be fine because you said it had to be 40vh, this always stays the same when you resize the width of your viewport and the text go smaller the viewport height is still 40vh. If you don't give the height of something it will automatically assign height auto

```
.col-content {
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #555555;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I added a min-height instead and it solved my problem without affecting the aesthetics